# No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' when using Entity Manager with spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, infinispan

I am migrating my code from spring boot 1.5.4 to 2.0.8. 
While doing so the entity manager throws an error when deploying on jboss :

when using @Autowired for EntityManager:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager'
```

and when using @PersistenceContext:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'
```

Something I observed is that this issue doesn't appear on jboss when I use the uber jar of infinispan embedded. I do not want to use the uber jar as it gives other issues.

**UPDATED** entire POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>print-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>print-web</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version> -->
    <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>

    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <version.infinispan.starter>1.0.4.Final</version.infinispan.starter>

    <infispan.version>7.2.0.Final</infispan.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
         <!-- <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion> -->
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId> 
              <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
           </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
         <!-- <exclusion> 
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion> -->
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId> <artifactId>infinispan-spring4-embedded</artifactId> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId> <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->


    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-spring4-embedded</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-cdi-embedded</artifactId>

    </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>            
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>   -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>       


    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-spring4-embedded</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-cdi-embedded</artifactId>
         <version>9.4.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>print-react</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media.jai</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media.jai</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>R8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>4.24.92</version> -->
        <version>10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>       
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I am pasting the full logs for @Autowired on EntityManager.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'printRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'em'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
```

NOTE: commented out the uber jar of infinispan (infinispan-embedded) which fixes this issue. But causes other major issues.

**UPDATE 2a:** print-react

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>print-react</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>print-react</name>
<description>Frontend React application for print</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    <node.version>v10.13.0</node.version>
    <yarn.version>v1.12.1</yarn.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>app/build</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>app</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                                <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>test</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**UPDATE 2 **

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchprintRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'em'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
    ... 70 more
```

**UPDATE 3**
The final solution is mentioned within the chat logs of the accepted answer.

Comment: Upgrade infinispan-starter to 2.1.3.Final

Comment: 2.1.3 also gave the same  error

Comment: Post the entire POM.

Comment: updated question with entire pom

Comment: See answer. Should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a *starter* module, you don't need to explicitly import other dependencies.
So remove:

```
infinispan-spring4-embedded
```

Than I see you're explicitly importing Spring Security.
Why don't you use **only** the *starter* module?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Regarding `Infinispan JCache`, I found out that Spring already supports the `JSR-107` cache annotations ([blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/14/cache-abstraction-jcache-jsr-107-annotations-support)).

I don't think CDI should be required at all. So procede by removing also

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-cdi-embedded</artifactId>
     <version>9.4.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also remove the explicit Hibernate import

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @stackMan10 Ok, you're using Weld. Then re-add the infinispan-cdi-embedded

Comment: I did try that. if I  add cdi-embedded it gives back the previous errors

Comment: @stackMan10 which version of cdi embedded are you using now?

Comment: I'm using 9.1.7.Final

Comment: @stackMan10 Could you update the question with the **current** POM?

Comment: I still get the exact same errors :( with both Autowired and PersistenceContext:
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager'

Comment: @stackMan10 Remove "hibernate-core". Hibernate is already imported from Boot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188525/discussion-between-stackman10-and-lppedd).